# Oracle query to find employee who has taken maximum number of leaves in last 1 month

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, aggregate-functions, oracle12c

I have these tables with the following columns :

> **Employee24**( *EMPLOYEEID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, GENDER* );
>
> **Leave25**( *EMPLOYEEID,LEAVEID, LEAVETYPE, STARTDATE, ENDDATE, NOOFDAYS* );

I want to write a query to find employee who has taken maximum number of leaves in last 1 month

```
SELECT * 
  FROM EMPLOYEE24 
 WHERE EMPLOYEEID IN (SELECT EMPLOYEEID 
                        FROM LEAVE25 
                       WHERE STARTDATE < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -1));
```

Comment: Hint use GROUP BY clause /aggregate function

Comment: You are on the right track, you only need to add the bit about 'maximum number of ...'. That is called a "top N query", search a bit for that term on stackoverflow, there are many questions and solutions...

Answer (score 1):

If your DB version is ***12c***, you may use ***Row Limiting Clause for Top-N Queries*** as below :

```
SELECT e.*, l.max_leaves
  FROM (SELECT employeeid, count(1) as max_leaves
        FROM LEAVE25 
        WHERE startdate >= add_months(sysdate, -1)
        GROUP BY employeeid           
       ) l JOIN
       EMPLOYEE24 e 
       ON ( e.employeeid = l.employeeid )
 ORDER BY l.max_leaves DESC
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES; -- including the same highest leave owners
```

If version is ***11g***, then use ***Dense_Rank and Count with a nested query*** as below :

```
SELECT e.*, l.max_leaves
  FROM (SELECT employeeid, count(1) as max_leaves, 
               dense_rank() over (order by count(1) desc) dr
        FROM LEAVE25 
        WHERE startdate >= add_months(sysdate, -1)
        GROUP BY employeeid           
       ) l JOIN
       EMPLOYEE24 e
       ON ( e.employeeid = l.employeeid )
 WHERE l.dr = 1;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo for* **11g**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cdfd9a/2)